# Name for a function which allows for many-one mapping and unmapped range elements

Tags: functions

Must I really refer to this as a "non-injective, non-bijective, non-surjective" function? Is there a shorter name for such a function?

Comment: You just call it a function.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you.